# Why is my parallax website so laggy when scrolling?

Tags: html, css, scroll, parallax

https://myfirstparallax.netlify.com/

I've been looking all over the internet for a solution to fix the lag I face when scrolling through the images and none of them seem to help explain why parallax scrolling would cause the lag. Is it because the image size is too big? 
Note: I know, my site is cringe worthy don't judge.

```css
body, html{
 height:100%;
 margin: 0;
 font-size: 16px;
 font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
 font-weight: 400;
 line-height:1.8em;
 color:#666;
}
/* ---------------------------------------------------------*/
p{
 font-sizes: 5em;
}

.name{
font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
font-size: 60px;

font-weight:normal;
margin-right: 135px;
margin-top: 14px;
padding-left: 20px;
color: white;

}



.main-nav{
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
  font-size:23px;
  list-style-type: none;
  opacity: 0.9;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  padding-top:10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  height: 64px;

  display:flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  

  border: 2px solid aqua
  background-image:url('../image/image1.jpg');
}

.main-nav:nth-child(4) {
 order: 1;
 float: right;
 }


li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  width:180px;
  
  transition-duration: 0.4s, 0.8s, 0.4s;
  transition-property: background, border-radius, color;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: #111;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width:180px;

  overflow: hidden;
  color: #fff;
  background: #4a89ca;
  border-radius: 1em;
  
}




/* ---------------------------------------------------------*/



.pimg1,
.pimg2,
.pimg3,
.pimg4{
 position: relative;
 opacity: 0.70;
 background-position: center;
 background-size: cover;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-attachment: fixed;
 
 /* Now is where the parallax Effect Begin */
}



.pimg1{
 background-image:url('../image/image1.jpg');
 min-height: 590px;
}

.pimg2{
 background-image:url('../image/image2.jpg');
 min-height: 600px;
}

.pimg3{
 background-image:url('../image/image3.jpg');
 min-height: 400px;
}

.pimg4{
 background-image:url('../image/image4.jpg');
 min-height: 600px;
}

.section{
 text-align: center;
 padding: 50px 80px;
}

.section-light {
 background-color: #f4f4f4;
 color: #666;
}

.section-dark {
 background-color: #282e34;
 color: #ddd;
}



.ptext{
 
 position:absolute;
 top:50%;
 width:100%;
 text-align:center;
 color:#000;
 font-size:27px;
 letter-spacing: 8px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 justify-content: center;
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 line-height: 41px;
}

.ptext-2{

 position:absolute;
 top:50%;
 width:100%;
 text-align:center;
 color:#000;
 font-size:27px;
 letter-spacing: 8px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 justify-content: center;
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 line-height: 41px;

}

.ptext-2 .border-2{
 background-color:#111;
 color: #fff;
 margin-top: -35px;
 padding: 20px;
 border-radius: 5px;
}


.ptext .border{
 background-color:#111;
 padding: 20px;
 border-radius: 5px;
}

.text-1{
  margin-top: -56px;
 
 }

.ptext .border.trans{
 background-color: transparent;
}

.grid-1{
 background-image:url('../image/grid1.jpg');
 height: 350px;
 width: 450px;
 background-position: center;
 background-size: cover;
 
}

.grid-2{
 background-image:url('../image/grid2.jpg');
 height: 350px;
 width: 450px;
 background-position: center;
 background-size: cover;
 
}
.grid-3{
 background-image:url('../image/grid3.jpg');
 height: 350px;
 width: 450px;
 background-position: center;
 background-size: cover;
 
}

.grid-4{
 background-image:url('../image/grid4.jpg');
 height: 350px;
 width: 450px;
 background-position: center;
 background-size: cover;
 
}

.grid-5{
 background-image:url('../image/grid5.jpg');
 height: 350px;
 width: 450px;
 background-position: center;
 background-size: cover;
 
}

.grid-6{
 background-image:url('../image/grid6.jpg');
 height: 350px;
 width: 450px;
 background-position: center;
 background-size: cover;
 
}




.cool-image{
 text-align: center;
 padding: 1px 20px;
}
.pict-1{
 margin-bottom: -8px;
 margin-top: 12px;
 }

.pict-2{
 text-align:center;
} 

.contacts{
 
 list-style-type:none;
 display: inline;
 

 float:right;
} 
 
.contacts-2{
 list-style-type:none;
 display: inline;
 float:left;
}  

.contacts-3{
 list-style-type:none;
 display: inline;
 text-align:center;
 margin-top:10px;
}  

.quick-fix{
 padding-bottom:60px;
}

.font-2{
 color: #fff;
}
 
.font-4{
font-family: 'Gloria Hallelujah', cursive;
color: black;
} 

.font-5{
 font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

@media(max-width:568px){
 .pimg1,
 .pimg2,
 .pimg3{
  background-attachment: scroll; 
  
 }
 
 .text-1{
  margin-top: -140px;
 }
 
 .grid-1{
  margin-left: -70px;
 }
}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Parallax Website Demo</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Gloria+Hallelujah" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">
  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  
</head>
<body>

<header class="main-header">
 

 <ul class="main-nav">
 <h1 class="name">The Purity of Css</h1>
   <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="second-page.html">Inspiration</a></li>
   <li><a href="second-page.html">Movie</a></li>
   <li><a href="second-page.html">Other</a></li>
   
 </ul>
 
</header>

<!--------------------------------------------------->
 <div class="pimg1">
  <div class="ptext font-2">
   <span class="border">
    Where do you see yourself in 5 years?
   </span>
  </div>
 </div>


 <section class="section section-light">
  <h2>Section One</h2>
  <p>
  As HTML grew, it came to encompass a wider variety of stylistic capabilities to meet 
  the demands of web developers. This evolution gave the designer more control over 
  site appearance, at the cost of more complex HTML. Variations in web browser
  implementations, such as ViolaWWW and WorldWideWeb, made consistent site 
  appearance difficult, and users had less control over how web content was displayed.
  The browser/editor developed by Tim Berners-Lee had style sheets that were hard-coded into 
  the program. The style sheets could therefore not be linked to documents on the web.
  Robert Cailliau, also of CERN, wanted to separate the structure from the presentation so that 
  different style
  sheets could describe different presentation for printing, screen-based presentations, 
  and editors. - Wikipedea
  </p>
 </section>  

 

<!---------------------------------------------------> 
 
 
 <div class="pimg2">
  <div class="ptext">
   <span class="border trans font-2">
    Will you be partying with friends?
   </span>
  </div>
 </div>
 
  <section class="section section-dark">
  <h2>Section Two</h2>
  <p>
  Tomorrowland is an electronic dance music festival held in Boom, Belgium. Tomorrowland was first held in 2005 and has since become one of the world's largest and most notable music festivals.
  It now stretches over 2 weekends and usually sells out in minutes. - Wikipedia
  </p>
 </section> 

 
 

<!---------------------------------------------------> 
 
 
 
 <div class="pimg3">
  <div class="text-1 ptext font-4">
   <span class="border trans">
   Traveling the world and living life?
   </span>
  </div>
 </div>
 
 <section class="section section-light">
  <h2>Section Three</h2>
  <p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut 
  labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco 
  laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate
  velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, 
  sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </p>
 </section> 

<!--------------------------------------------------->
 
 <div class="pimg4">
  <div class="ptext-2 font-5">
  
   <span class="border-2">
     Or maybe following the footsteps of 
    scholars before you
   </span>
   
  </div>
 </div>
 
 
<!--------------------------------------------------->
 
 
 <section class="section-light cool-image quick-fix">
  <h2 class="pict-1">A collection of beautiful places</h2>
  <p class="pict-2">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut 
  </p>
  
 <img class="grid-1"> 
 <img class="grid-2">
 <img class="grid-3">
 <img class="grid-4">
 <img class="grid-5">
 <img class="grid-6">
 
 
 </section>  
<!--------------------------------------------------------->

 
 
  <p class="pict-2">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut 
  </p>
  
   <ol class="contacts">
     <li>Head north on N Halsted St</li>
     <li>Turn right on W Diversey Pkwy</li>
     <li>Turn left on N Orchard St</li>
   </ol>

   <ol class="contacts-2">
     <li>Head north on N Halsted St</li>
     <li>Turn right on W Diversey Pkwy</li>
     <li>Turn left on N Orchard St</li>
   </ol>

   <ol class="contacts-3">
     <li>Head north on N Halsted St</li>
     <li>Turn right on W Diversey Pkwy</li>
     <li>Turn left on N Orchard St</li>
   </ol>

 

 
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using a very heavy graphic images. This simple page weights **44.1MB**. And 90% of this weight is 9 images you used. It's much harder for your machine to work with that. (FYI average website weight is ~2MB according to [this article](https://www.machmetrics.com/speed-blog/website-size-the-average-web-page-size-is-more-than-2mb-twice-the-size-of-the-average-page-just-3-years-ago/))

Compress your graphics, on a service like https://imagecompressor.com/ or any other one. You can also use "Save for Web" in Photoshop, or any modern image editor.

I'd say this page can look same with 5-10 times reduced weight. And parallax will definitely work much smoother. It will also boost your page load time.

Comment: Even after I compressed it it still seems to be really laggy. Not much seem to change as a result.

Answer (score 0):

At first glance,
you are loading too much content.

And too big.

It's an actually natural behavior that the page would freeze in case of images at original size (for example, on 4K).

It's not the scrolling per sé, it's your web itself.

I would implement a lazy loading (consider using libraries like this: http://jquery.eisbehr.de/lazy/)
And, for sure, a smaller preview.

If you want to load the original sized image, do it in a modal or so.